# If condition is not met but code executes anyways

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a slight challenge with this code below. The Condition in the If-clause is not met but the code triggers anyways. Anyone got an idea what I can do about this? (I already tried going around with an If Not Statement but this won't work either.)

This is supposed to be a little worktime tracker for my learning and/or work I'm doing in my free time.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Timestamp As Date
Dim myProject As String
Dim myWTI As Integer
Dim myPayment As String
Dim myPaymentDetail As String
Dim i As Integer
Public Sub StartTime()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

myProject = [cell_Project]
myWTI = [cell_WorktimeInterval]
myPayment = [cell_Payment]
myPaymentDetail = [cell_Paymentdetail]

If myWTI Or myProject = Empty Then
    MsgBox "No Project and/or WTI chosen.", vbCritical, "Error: No Project/WTI"
    Exit Sub
Else (rest of the code - this runs perfectly fine without this If-clause)
```

Comment: @DirkReichel - Thank's, but SQLGeorge had the answer I was looking for.  I simply forgot about the different data types.

Comment: ah... the code was also wrong in another way... still `If myWTI * Len(myProject) Then` would work in that case :P (you still would need to swap the `Then` and `Else` part)

Comment: I'll keep it in mind if i need to do some dirty work on stuff like that again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA, you cannot write something like

```
If myWTI Or myProject = Empty Then
```

That has no sense.
You need something like this:

```
If myWTI = 0 Or myProject = "" Then
```

Also please note that myInt is declared as Integer, and myProject is declared as String. Therefore, they cannot be "null" or "empty", they always need a value to be assigned, like 0, or "".

Comment: You're perfectly right ... How didn't I think about this myself. Different data types... Thank's a lot!

Comment: You're wrong about the first statement, it's perfectly legitimate in VBA.

Comment: @FlorentB. If `myWTI` is a `Boolean`, then certainly. But not for `String` or `Integer` values.

Comment: @FlorentB. Yeah, but then it checks if it is <> 0. But he wanted to check if it is empty. Like when you say in natural language "if my glass or my cup is empty"

Comment: @Vegard The If statement apply to any number and boolean. Also a boolean is an integer in VBA (True=-1 and False=0)

Comment: @Vegard It also works with Integer. But then it has the meaning of  `if myWTI <> 0`. This is a check on binary level, but such tricks are only for nerds ;)  He certaintly did not want this. He wanted to look if it is "empty" or "zero".

Comment: @Vegard that's why I said legitimate and not correct for his case.

Comment: Some confusion over words aside, we all seem to agree. I meant that the operation was legal but the syntax would make the result polar to OP's question. Sorry for the poor wording ;)

Comment: @SQLGeorge I like the kind of thinking behind if myWTI <>0 and the binary thing. I'll keep it in mind when I come to this situation again (or I rework my code). Thanks again!